# extract parts of php string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a result set that is being displayed as a string like this.

```
[{"name:" "John Doe", "Class:" 45}]
```

I want to extract part of that string for example, I would just like to extract "John Doe" and "45"

is that possible?

Comment: If your string is not in JSON format you can use `explode()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Why don't you convert it to json and process it as below:

```
$string='[{"name:" "John Doe", "Class:" 45}]';
$json=json_decode($string);

echo $json->name."\n";
echo $json->Class;
```

**EDIT**

I observed later, your string isn't a valid json:

```
$string='{"name": "John Doe", "Class": 45}'; // <-- if you can make it as valid json, you can use this method. 
$json=json_decode($string);

echo $json->name."\n";
echo $json->Class;
```

[*DEMO*](http://codepad.org/y0hfXl0R)

You may want to read more about json.

1. [JSON Example](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)
2. [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)